# How can I add stroke to Chart.js Pie Charts?

Tags: javascript, css, charts

I want each section in the pie chart to have its own stroke color. Right now, it only seems to do a global stroke--can I get a stroke over each pie segment? I've tried the following, with no luck:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.segmentShowStroke = true;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = [{
  value: 300,
  color: "#F7464A",
  highlight: "#FF5A5E",
  stroke: "#FF0000", // Doesn't work
  label: "Red"
}, {
  value: 50,
  color: "#46BFBD",
  highlight: "#5AD3D1",
  strokeColor: "#00FF00", // Doesn't work
  label: "Green"
}, {
  value: 100,
  color: "#FDB45C",
  highlight: "#FFC870",
  segmentStrokeColor: "#88FF00", // Doesn't work
  label: "Yellow"
}];
/**
 * Whether or not segmentStrokeColor is enabled,
 * the previous stroke options do not work.
 */
var options = {
  segmentStrokeColor: "black" // Works. Defaults to "white" if removed
};
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

Note that even if `segmentStrokeColor` is removed from the `options` variable, the previous attempts to color the stroke of each pie segment do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Pie and Bar charts, the Pie one doesn't support a *strokeColor* per segment, it only uses a global one.

The only way to achieve what you want is to extend the Pie chart, copying the *addData* method and using **segment.strokeColor** instead of **this.options.segmentStrokeColor**:

```
Chart.types.Pie.extend({
    name: 'SegmentStrokeColorPie',
    addData : function(segment, atIndex, silent){
      ...
      [Copy all the addData method here, only change the line below]
      ...
          strokeColor : segment.strokeColor,
      ...
      ...
    }
});

var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red",
        strokeColor: "#FF0000"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green",
        strokeColor: "#00FF00"
    }
];

new Chart(ctx).SegmentStrokeColorPie(data);
```